# How to access the ci svn commit log?

Tags: svn, logging, commit

Hey I want to see the full commit log in svn, there must be another commit log than rightclick tortoise svn and than show log.
Where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's only 1 log. It can get filtered to show a subset of the history however so maybe that's what you're looking for.

Try a commit log for the root of the repository, not a sub folder or branch. And uncheck the "stop on copy/rename" option to see the log continue from the parent when a branch was created.

Comment: to be honest, I also only knew this log but my boss asked me for the commit log and said that there is something else. So my information is limited. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is the Subversion command line client (which comes with TortioseSVN). It's the `svn.exe` file in something like `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe`.

The command line `svn` command will look like this:

```
C> svn log -r1:HEAD http://svn.corp/svn/project/trunk
```

This will print out a *log* that could be parsed with PowerShell, Python, or Perl.

There are quite a file options. For example:

```
C> svn log -r1:HEAD -v --stop-on-copy http://svn.corp/svn/project/branches/4.5
```

Will print out the log, but stop where the 4.5 branch was copied from trunk. The `-v` will show you the files too.

```
C> svn log -r1:HEAD -v --xml --stop-on-copy http://svn.corp/svn/project/branches/4.5
```

Will print out the log in XML output which programming languages have an easier time parsing.

The `-r` parameter is the revision list you want. You can do this by revision number, or by date.

```
C> svn help log
```

Will print out complete details of the command.

You may need to find what your boss is looking for, and then use another scripting language like PowerShell or Python to manipulate the log output into the format they want.